# Unusual quadratic property

Tags: quadratics, finite-differences

We were learning about functions in our class, and there came a question:
If $f(x+2)-5f(x+1)+6f(x)=0$

$f(0)=2$ and

$f(1)=5$, what is f(x)?

*My approach*:
I found $f(2),f(3)$,..... And they don't seem to follow any general GP or AP pattern.

So I took help of the solution

*Solution*:

Let a and b be the roots of the equation
**$x^2-5x+6=0$**

**$a=2,b=3$**

As $a\ne b$,

$f(x)=A.a^x+B.b^x=A.2^x+B.3^x$

From the given values of $f(0)$ and $f(1)$,
A and B are found.
$f(x)$ comes out to be $2^x +3^x$

***My questions:***

1. Why did they and how could they  compare the original equation with a quadratic equation?

2.How f(x) could be explicitly related to the roots of the quadratic equation?

Comment: This is a recurrence relation

Comment: it is hard to read, you have the correct syntax already, just enclose math formulas between `$`.

Comment: @zwim sorry Im a newbie.... didn't know it....I have altered it now

Comment: tag "functional- analysis" is inappropriate, should be replaced by "finite-differences" or "finite-difference-methods"

Comment: @P.Lawrence ok I'll change it right away

Comment: What is the domain of $f$ ?

Comment: It has not been specified, so I guess it's $R$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard [solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) for a homogenous linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients such as $f_n+bf_{n-1}+cf_{n-2}=0$ is to find the roots of its characteristic equation $r^2+br+c=0$.  If they are distinct, say $r_1$ and $r_2$, then each solution to the relation takes the form $f_n=Ar_1^n+Br_2^n$.

Comment: Note:  Binet's formula for the Fibonacci sequence can be derived this way

Comment: Thanks....let me think for a while...

Comment: Ok.  Here's a check:  $f_n+bf_{n-1}+cf_{n-2}=Ar_1^n+Br_2^n+b(Ar_1^{n-1}+Br_2^{n-1})+c(Ar_1^{n-2}+Br_2^{n-2})$ $=Ar_1^{n-2}(r_1^2+br_1+c)+Br_2^{n-2}(r_2^2+br_2+c)=0$

Comment: Does this theory apply if $f$ is a function over the reals? I am familiar with this for sequences but... what if $f$ is real function? How do we solve OP's problem then in this more general setting?

Comment: Ok here's what I understood: there exists an equation of the form an.f(n)+a(n-1).f(n-1)........ So we take a "characteristic" equation of the form an.r^n + a(n-1).r^(n-1) +...... We find the solutions of this equation and generalise a solution of the form Ar1^x+Br2^x-1......

Comment: But I'm not able to digest the fact that you have taken f(x) as some r^x, i.e, assumed it to be a xth degree term. Secondly, how do you generalize that it will be of the form of Ar1^x+.....?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I did some research and I'm pretty satisfied with the characteristic equation....now just help me out with the generalisation thing and how it is true

Comment: @DatBoi:  Did you see the "check" in my above comment showing it's a solution?  One way to derive it would be to write $\pmatrix{f_n\\f_{n-1}}=\pmatrix{-b&&-c\\1&&0}\pmatrix{f_{n-1}\\f_{n-2}}=\pmatrix{-b&&-c\\1&&0}^{n-1}\pmatrix{f_{1}\\f_{0}}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks, I got it!